# Numpy: "Adding" index and colon

Tags: python, numpy

I have

```
>>> foo = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> foo[1,2,1] = 1
>>> idx = 1,2
```

I would like to get the equivalent of

```
>>> foo[1,2,:]
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

using `idx` (to iterate through `idx`) . Both approaches that I tried didn't work out:

```
>>> foo[idx, :]
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
>>> foo[((idx,)+(slice(None),))]
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `foo[idx]`.  Read the following to see how I arrived at this.

---

`foo[1,2,:]` is effectively:

```
In [379]: foo[(1,2,slice(None))]
Out[379]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

The Python interpreter converts the `1,2,:` to this tuple, and passes it to the `foo.__getitem__` method.

So we just have to find the right way of constructing the tuple.  One is:

```
In [380]: tuple(idx)+(slice(None),)
Out[380]: (1, 2, slice(None, None, None))
```

resulting in:

```
In [381]: foo[tuple(idx)+(slice(None),)]
Out[381]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

Actually I don't need the `tuple` call, `idx` is already a tuple

```
In [386]: idx
Out[386]: (1, 2)
In [387]: idx+(slice(None),)
Out[387]: (1, 2, slice(None, None, None))
```

I would need `tuple([1,2])` if `idx` was initialed as a list.

Double actually, the solution is even simpler. Since we are using `:` for the last dimension, we can omit it.  And since `idx` is tuple, it already indexes the first 2 dimensions.

```
In [394]: foo[idx]
Out[394]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

This pair of calls may lend some clarity:

```
In [396]: foo[(1,2)]
Out[396]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
In [397]: foo[[1,2]]
Out[397]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Is there a generalization of this, say for `1,2, 0:2`?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> foo[idx + (slice(None),)]
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

Comment: A bit of explanation about tuples and slice objects might help the poster.